# Import of Dataframe from .csv imported as OBJECT and not FLOAT

Tags: python-3.x

I have imported a csv from Github containing as a dataframe (using link from raw version) and this shows up as follows:

[image]

I now want to plot markers on a Folium map from the Latitude and Longitude from the list, but when I check the types:

```
station.dtypes
Name         object
Latitude     object
Longitude    object
```

The Latitude and Longitude have imported as objects and not float64 which is leading to problems in plotting the markers.

How can I convert these? Or even better, ensure that they are imported correctly in the first place?

I tried :

```
pd.to_numeric(station['Longitude'], errors='coerce')
```

The column is then printed and at the end it says:

```
Name: Longitude, dtype: float64
```

But station.dtypes remains as object :

```
Name         object
Latitude     object
Longitude    object
```

I also tried importing like this

```
station = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/
Minchy1973/Coursera_ Capstone/master/Station_Location.csv",
                  dtype={'Latitude':float})
```

I had an error (ValueError: could not convert string to float: '51.49787 +/- 0.000011 (from 3 readings)' - so I corrected that in the data and tried to load it all back again, but I am still getting:

Comment: Hi @Matt, you don't have to go through excel to resolve this. Python is not reading because there is a value called ``` '51.49787 +/- 0.000011 (from 3 readings)' ``` in the column. In this case you can pick ```51.49787```. Let me know if you need help how to do it in python.

Comment: Hi - thank you! You are right, that weird value was all the way down in the data and I should have checked that for good practise to see it was clean. That was the cause of the problem. All works now, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excel file was formatted with right-align and then converted to csv. For some reason, the align was throwing out the import as the correct dtype. I formatted the excel back to normal, reloaded the csv into github and now my import shows up as float64 where it should